# In Android, How do I close the number of android applications in the background amounting to the required ram e.g. 25mb

Tags: android, memory-management, service, cpu-usage, ram

**In Android**

How do I close the number of android applications in the background amounting to the required ram e.g. 25mb?

Basically the code below enables me to check the amount of available memory within Android, what I would then like to do is. If this available memory amount is below a certain number of megabytes, then close applications in the background that make up the difference.

E.g if after running subroutine (to discover how many available megabytes are available), only 17mb are available when 25mb are required. I'd like to close applications running in the background (besides the current app) which amount to the remaining required 8mb.

Code:

```
public void MemoryCheck(){
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

    if (availableMegs <25){
        ///Close apps amounting to the difference in available megabytes from required mb
    }

}
```

Hopefully I've been clear, if not feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: and what for? OS should take care of this ...

Comment: Android O.S, title modified

Comment: still, Android OS should take care of this ... if your app needs more memory OS will close other apps ... there is no need to closing other apps by yourself

Comment: Those memory numbers are not useful at all. Android isn't even trying to keep lots of free memory because that would mean that it would needlessly have to kill background apps. Free RAM is wasted cache space. Available also may not mean "available to you".

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS is expected to [kill old applications](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) to free up memory if the current foreground application needs more resources. If you are under the application memory limit, the Android OS should free up resources for you automatically. You can read [more on memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html), which describes how to query the OS for how much heap space can be allocated for your application.